# Pass UILabel through a function

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I wonder how can I pass a `UIlabel` to a function ?

I wrote a function that gives a UILabel text from a table, but now i want to run the function with the `UIlabel` passed to the head of the function. Just like you would do with the text or `int`. Do I need a pointer or can I pass the label the normal way?

```
-(void)giveText:(NSString) *textinsert  
{
  label1.text=textinsert;
}
```

How could I save all the labels inside an array and run through the array?

Comment: I hope `..:(NSString) *textinsert` is a typo.

Comment: i translated it in a hurry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
 NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//label Creation
UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];

//add into array
[arr addObject:lbl];


// get label From array one by one
for (UILabel *lbl in arr) {
 //pass label to function
    [self passLabel:lbl];
}

-(void)passLabel:(UILabel *)lbl

{
// do here
}
```

Comment: thnx :) this works except the [self passLabel:lbl]; doesn't work at least not on os6 but i use this instead lbl.text;

Comment: what is Problem in [self passLabel:lbl];

Comment: Why do you put the `UILabel` into an array then take it out in a `for loop` seems a bit pointless?

Comment: the problem is that passLabel is not supported anymore. At least thats what the err message says.

Comment: duno. i woted up and marked it the right anwsere. dont know why i got -6 its a good question easy but good

Answer (score 1):

To be honest after reading comments that you have put I don't believe you understanding what's going on at all.

This `-(void)giveText:(NSString) *textinsert` will just not work syntax error this method should be `-(void)giveText:(NSString *)textinsert`, but that isn't your problem.

From what I understand about what you are asking you want to pass a `UILabel` to the method.

So what you want to be doing is is something like

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [self giveText:label1];
}

- (void)giveText:(UILabel *)label
{
    // Do what ever with label.
}
```

So what is going on?

We have created the method `giveText:` that takes a `UILabel` as a parameter then we call this method from `someMethod` by doing `[self giveText:label1];` we pass in the `UILabel` that we have created.

Answer (score -2):

you can pass label the same way as for example nsstring.

I think you shouldn't pass label to function if you are simply want to change ot's text.
Just create function which returns string

```
label.text = [self getLabelText];
- (NSString *) getLabelText {
    NSString *text = @"text";
    return text;
}
```

Comment: I think it is not smart to pass UI object to function just to change it's value. It makes code less reusable and it;s not OOP way. Far more convenient is to make function that will return string than pass label and change it's value there. Tomorrow he will decided to change label to textView and he will need to change function prototype, change function body. Again you can need this string to be returned in label and textView. What you will do? create two function. one to change label second to change textView?

Comment: Read my comment to the end) There 2 examples why. I mean exactly this situation. Person is asking question because he needs advice, i've just advised. and to followed it or not and to decide were it helpful is on the person who asked

Comment: i'm not going to run in details here because it's completely out of question's scope. So just one word - MVC.

Comment: easily. sorry but i'm not on the interview. i have more important stuff to do. good luck